# Android development error, Using Eclipse

Tags: android, cordova

im having this problem with my project. and I dont know what to do. please help me. here is the logcat for the application ran by simulator 2.2

```
02-23 07:48:27.474: I/PhoneGapLog(274): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
02-23 07:48:27.474: D/DroidGap(274): DroidGap.onCreate()
02-23 07:48:27.485: D/DroidGap(274): DroidGap.init()
02-23 07:48:27.653: D/DroidGap(274): DroidGap.loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/index.html, 9000)
02-23 07:48:27.693: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(274): Ignore this event
02-23 07:48:27.804: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(274): Ignore this event
02-23 07:48:36.753: D/DroidGap(274): DroidGap.loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
02-23 07:48:36.753: D/DroidGap(274): DroidGap: url=file:///android_asset/www/index.html baseUrl=file:///android_asset/www/
02-23 07:48:37.245: D/dalvikvm(274): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 2060 objects / 177440 bytes in 140ms
02-23 07:48:37.423: D/dalvikvm(274): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 1065 objects / 68792 bytes in 55ms
02-23 07:48:39.503: I/Database(274): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at source line 25467
02-23 07:48:40.154: E/Contact Query(274): Value {"birthday":null,"ims":null,"nickname":null,"rawId":null,"urls":null,"organizations":null,"emails":null,"phoneNumbers":null,"photos":null,"id":null,"name":{"middleName":null,"familyName":null,"formatted":"","givenName":"","honorificSuffix":null,"honorificPrefix":null},"categories":null,"addresses":null,"displayName":null,"note":null} at 0 of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
02-23 07:48:40.154: E/Contact Query(274): org.json.JSONException: Value {"birthday":null,"ims":null,"nickname":null,"rawId":null,"urls":null,"organizations":null,"emails":null,"phoneNumbers":null,"photos":null,"id":null,"name":{"middleName":null,"familyName":null,"formatted":"","givenName":"","honorificSuffix":null,"honorificPrefix":null},"categories":null,"addresses":null,"displayName":null,"note":null} at 0 of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
02-23 07:48:40.154: E/Contact Query(274):  at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:96)
02-23 07:48:40.154: E/Contact Query(274):  at org.json.JSONArray.getJSONArray(JSONArray.java:459)
02-23 07:48:40.154: E/Contact Query(274):  at com.phonegap.ContactManager.execute(ContactManager.java:87)
02-23 07:48:40.154: E/Contact Query(274):  at com.phonegap.api.PluginManager$1.run(PluginManager.java:150)
02-23 07:48:40.154: E/Contact Query(274):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
02-23 07:48:40.543: D/PhoneGapLog(274): Error in error callback: Contacts2 = ReferenceError: Can't find variable: elert
02-23 07:48:40.543: D/PhoneGapLog(274): file:///android_asset/www/phonegap-1.4.1.js: Line 717 : Error in error callback: Contacts2 = ReferenceError: Can't find variable: elert
02-23 07:48:40.543: I/Web Console(274): Error in error callback: Contacts2 = ReferenceError: Can't find variable: elert at file:///android_asset/www/phonegap-1.4.1.js:717
02-23 07:48:42.493: D/dalvikvm(274): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 3339 objects / 726120 bytes in 158ms
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a a little garbled... can you edit your question, wrap the stuff in a code block and give it some newlines? Just at first blush I see a lot of PhoneGap stuff, perhaps you can tag your post with that as well. Anyway it's hard to decipher what's going on, which is the significant error, etc.

Oh there it is... give me a moment...

Well it looks like you're trying to coerce some single JSONObject into a JSONArray... which it seems is bad news. Can you post some code?

Comment: I dont know which is which. im very sorry. this project is given by my professor and he wants me to bypass the login privileges as of the moment he said.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
02-23 07:48:39.503: I/Database(274): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at source line 25467
```

Looks like there is an error connecting to the database.

Which in turn causes this error line:

```
 02-23 07:48:40.154: E/Contact Query(274): Value {"birthday":null,"ims":null,"nickname":null,"rawId":null,"urls":null,"organizations":null,"emails":null,"phoneNumbers":null,"photos":null,"id":null,"name":{"middleName":null,"familyName":null,"formatted":"","givenName":"","honorificSuffix":null,"honorificPrefix":null},"categories":null,"addresses":null,"displayName":null,"note":null} at 0 of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

Because all the values that are probably supposed to be pulled from the database are null values, and thus why your application is failing.

The first error tells you exactly which line of code is failing: 25467.

Look at that line in your project.

Comment: Thank you. but is there anyway i could bypass the login into database as of the moment? or should I delete or add any events regarding this project? thank you

Comment: You would have to disable any method/function calls that require data based on that login. You could comment it out, but you would just end up with a program that doesn't process sections of code.

Comment: You can safely ignore that sqlite error code 14. You will always get that error when you new up an Android WebView.

Answer (score 0):

I think I could help if I could see your HTML code. It appears that you are trying to do a navigator.contacts.find() and it isn't returning any results. The other thing I notice is your error callback is trying to execute "elert" but that probably should be "alert".